# Get Geometric Mean Over Window in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following pyspark dataframe

| Car | Time | Val1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 21 |
| 3 | 2 | 33 |

I want to get the geometric mean of all the cars at each time, resulting df should look like this:

| time | geo_mean |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5.2414827884178 |
| 2 | 19.065333718304 |

I know how to calculate the arithmetic average with the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
        "aritmethic_average",
        F.avg(F.col("Val1")).over(W.partitionBy("time"))
    )
```

But I'm unsure how to accomplish the same thing with geometric means.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. First get product of all values in the same group, then get the Xth's root where X is the number of rows in the same group. And Xth's root = power of 1/X

```
df = df.groupby('Time').agg(F.pow(F.product('Val1'), 1/F.count('Val1')))
```

ref: https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/geometric-mean.html

Answer (score 2):

Using the standard definition of the geometric mean [image: standard definition] might lead to very large numbers during the [calculation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/geometric-mean-two-methods/).

Using the [equivalent formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) [image: geomeanformula] might be better if the groups become larger:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('ln_val1', F.log('Val1')) \
    .groupBy('Time') \
    .mean('ln_val1') \
    .withColumn('geo_mean', F.exp('avg(ln_val1)')) \
    .drop('avg(ln_val1)') \
    .show()
```

Result:

```
+----+-----------------+
|Time|         geo_mean|
+----+-----------------+
|   1|5.241482788417792|
|   2|19.06533371830357|
+----+-----------------+
```